# What do you call things made out of natural waste materials?

Tags: word-choice

How do you categorize things (say, a toy, doll or idol) made out of natural wastes like leaves, trunks, etc., from nature?

Comment: I'm not sure about things made from natural materials, but those made out of waste products usually state on them 'Made from recycled materials'.

Comment: I wouldn't characterize leaves and bark and such as "waste"— in urban areas, where they are a nuisance and get hauled away, yes, but I would think materials for handicrafts would be harvested wild or farmed, not collected from curb strips and freeway medians.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure you'll find a perfect word here, but many manufacturers use **[eco-friendly](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Environmentally_friendly)**, **[reclaimed](https://www.google.com/search?q=reclaimed%20definition)**, **organic** or the catch-all **[green](http://www.epa.gov/greenerproducts/)** to describe such products. I think these words all capture the repurposing *of waste* to make other products.

Answer (score 2):

Labeling the use of such materials depends on where and how they were obtained. If they were harvested (taken from living things), then you can label them as *made from all-natural materials*. If you obtained them from the ground, that is, did not take them from living plants, *made from eco-friendly, recycled, all-natural materials* or any shortened version.

Labeling something as *made from organic materials* simply because they were once living matter is deceptive in the US, because *organic* implies *freedom from pesticides or unnatural substances*. This precludes things gathered from the roadside, or from areas where any spraying or fertilizing might have taken place in the three-years (or more, depending) prior (in the US).

You can also label either/all as being *biodegradable.*

Comment: Yes 'organic' is a protected word, a quite ridiculous word to chose for the purpose I might add, since anything non-mineral is 'organic' in some sense.

Answer (score 1):

I would call that stuff organic or [organic matter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Organic_matter). However, depending on where you're from, different countries have different [standards](http://www.organicconsumers.org/articles/article_15106.cfm) on what constitutes organic material.

Comment: say if you are making a doll out of coconut shell is it still called organic matter?

Comment: Of course you could. Anything derived from living organisms is clearly organic.

Comment: made from all-natural materials is more appropriate than saying organic unless they are from certified organic agricultural areas.

Comment: What do you mean by appropriate? The USDA has standards for granting the "organic" label.

Comment: @Susan the traditional definition of the word "organic" does not have that limitation. Modern definitions do, however.

Comment: I would even go so far as saying that "all natural" is incredibly misleading. Just look at cereal boxes that advertise this.

Comment: I hardly think that coconut shells, leaves and twigs are subject to practices found in the making of breakfast cereal.

Comment: The USDA, for example, would oversee cereal and textiles.

Comment: There's nothing unnatural about monosodium glutamate...or cobra venom, for that matter.  It is like a box of sugar candy that advertises itself as 'Fat Free'.

Comment: @Oldcat - there **is nothing** unnatural about MSG or cobra venom - who said there was? Also, sugar is (breakdown product of) a starch, or simple sugar, not a fat. It **is** fat free. What is your objection? Do you understand the difference between different kinds or organic compounds? Many harmful compounds are organic, but not natural.

Comment: it was a comment on @tylerham's outrage that 'natural' was being used in a way that violated his own positive association with the word.  In practice, 'natural' is a noise word when describing a product.  The sugar being 'fat free' is similar, as the slogan is trying to hitch a positive association of fat free = good, low calorie and healthy, where candy is only good tasting. I can't think of anything 'unnatural' that can go in a box of cereal.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps, *recycled* would be more accurate.

Comment: I would assume that recycle is you destroy and create one out of it, but making use of the same without loosing its shape ??

Comment: then "made from recycled materials" or "reclaimed materials" fits